# Location manager delegate is not being called in ios objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am trying to develop an app that can get the location attributes of every location phone moves.
This is the code I have right now for getting a location of device

ViewController.h

```
            @interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
            {
                CLLocationManager   *locationManager;
                CMMotionManager     *motionManager;
            }
            @property(nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
            @end
```

ViewController.m

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

- (void)startAllDataRec
{
    [self getLocation];
}

- (void)getLocation
{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
   {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
   }

   //Checking authorization status
   if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] &&   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
   {
    NSLog(@"you are denied a permission");
   }
   else
   {
    //Location Services Enabled, let's start location updates
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        mLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        mLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        mSpeed = currentLocation.speed;
        mAlt = currentLocation.altitude;
        mCourse = currentLocation.course;
        NSLog(@"lat lon speed alt course = %f, %f, %f, %f, %f", mLat, mLon, mSpeed, mAlt, mCourse);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.speedLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", mSpeed];
        });

    }
    else{NSLog(@"current location is nil");};
}
```

The problem is, the delegate is not being called at any time or in other words its not getting triggered even when I am giving the access permission
Is there anything that I am missing on and need to be called first?

Comment: add locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; in getLocation method and call getLocation in viewwillappear. You also need to ask user permission before checking location. I see none of this. Google a CLLocationManager tutorial. Tons of them are out there.

Comment: I do have checked lot of tutorials on CLLocations however I didnt see any user permission issue. but I see what you mean, I will try to see what I can do.

Comment: I have updated my question and have aded the authorization access but still the problem is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason-- since you didn't mention it-- is that you don't have `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your app's Info.plist file. This is required (since iOS 8) if you want "always" location updates.

A couple of other things:

- You should implement `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` in the delegate, because that's where `CLLocationManager` will tell you if the user gave permission for location info.
- Your `respondsToSelector` check is unnecessary unless you're supporting iOS 7 or earlier.